# Prime Number program

Tags: c, numbers

I want to make a program in C language which will take the user input and I would not be able to understand the logic of the loop.

```
for ( c = 2 ; c <= n - 1 ; c++ )
```

The program code is given below:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
   int n, c;

   printf("Enter a number to check if it is prime\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   for ( c = 2 ; c <= n - 1 ; c++ )
   {
      if ( n % c == 0 )
      {
         printf("%d is not prime.\n", n);
         break;
      }
   }
   if ( c == n )
      printf("%d is prime.\n", n);

   getch();
}
```

I have used the for loop which will end up the statement of `n - 1` in for loop. If I will give the input `11` then it will end up on `11 - 1 = 10` then how it will give up the logic of  `if(c == n) { printf("%d", n);`?

Comment: try stepping through with a debugger to see where you have made an incorrect assumption

Comment: Are you asking how the program works? I'm confused, didn't you write it yourself?

Comment: Please look on Stack Overflow.

Comment: how i can transfer this question to stack overflow i am not very fimilar with this site please guide me. this is the algorithm i have written it is not written by me. the truth is that i would not be able to understand the logic of prime numbers in c ..

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra you can flag it for moderator attention, or the community will migrate it when we get 5 votes

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. So your `for` loop is checking from 2 (which is greater than 1) to `n-1`(which is just less than actal number) and because of this loop value of `c` will reach upto entered number, if and only if entered number is prime else it would have `break` in between.

Comment: I think it is enough if c runs till n/2

Comment: @EarlOfEgo Actually it is enough to test till `√n' as Sharon pointed out.

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra check posted answer, don't understand you seems off-line but question is just 56min old!!!

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra First try to google any question, if you didn't get answer then come here. Do some effort by yourself first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I will give the input `11` then it will end up on `11 - 1 = 10` then how it will give up the logic of  `if(c == n) { printf("%d", n);`?

Now correctly understand your for loop condition:

```
for ( c = 2 ; c <= n - 1 ; c++ )
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
              2 <= 11 - 1  -> True   // {for block executes }
              3 <= 11 - 1  -> True   // {for block executes }
                 :
                 :
              9 <= 11 - 1  -> True   // {for block executes }
              10 <= 11 - 1  -> True  // {for block executes }
              11 <= 11 - 1  -> False  breaks //{And Now for block NOT executes}

if (c == n)
    ^^^^^^
   11 == 11 -> True  // {if block executes}
```

According to for loop condition `c <= n - 1`, loop breaks when `c` value becomes equals to `n`. So if `n` is equals to  `11` loop condition is true for `c = 2` to `c = 10`, in each iteration `c` increments by one (using `c++` increment) when `c` becomes `11` (ot say `n`) then condition `c <= n - 1` become false and loop breaks.

In if condition (after for loop) `c` value compared with `n`. that is:

```
if ( c == n )
//   11 == 11  that is true
```

for `n` = `11` it becomes and `c` = `11` if condition evaluates true and `printf()` associated with if executes.

---

It is also important to understand that the for-loop only terminates for `c = n` when `n` is a prime number, but if suppose `n` is a non-prime number then for-loop will break for `c` value less then `n - 1` due to `break;` statement in nested `if` block in for-loop.

```
for( c = 2; c <= n - 1; c++ ) 
{
  if(n % c == 0)<=="for Non-prime `n`, if condition will be true for some `c < n - 1`"
  {  ^^^^^^^^^^^ True 
     printf("%d is not prime.\n", n);
     break; <== "move control outside for-loop"
  }  //      | 
}    //      |
// <---------+ // if break; executes control moves here with c < n - 1
if (c == n)<== "this condition will evaluates FALSE"  
   ^^^^^^^^ False
```

For example if `n = 8` then in very first iteration of for-loop with value `c = 2` if condition `if(n % c == 0)` that evaluates as `if(8 % 2 == 0)` == `if( 0 == 0)` = True and `break;` statement inside if-block moves control outside for-loop(as shown in figure).

Because this time for loop not terminated due to `c <= n - 1` condition but braked because of  `if(n % c == 0)` so out-side for-loop `c` value is less than `n` hence  `if (c == n)` evaluates as False.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Chauhan thankx buddy i can understand the loop now properly.

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra Very good, I am glad that I could help you..Good Luck! :)

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra No problem Tayyab, It always take it to understand things correctly. Good point is your attitude towards learning.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i want to know little bit  about the modulus sign that . if n=8. the for loop will end on c=7 like this if(c=2;c<=n-1;c++) {
             if (n%c==0){
                    printf("it is not a prime number",n);
                    }
} but how it would be possible if n=8 the loop will end on 7 (8%7==0)? i am not getting this last point

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra No for `n = 8` loop terminates due to `breaks;`  statement in `if` (the `if` in for-loop) See for `n = 8` in very first iteration of for loop when `c = 2` the for-loop condition `c <= n - 1` that is `(2 <= 7)` evaluates to True and in for if's condition `( n % c == 0 )` that is `8 % 2 == 0` again evaluates True  so if-block executes and after `printf("%d is not prime.\n", n);` break-statement terminates for-loop.

Comment: Well explained with perfect example

Answer (score 2):

The for loop loops from `c = 2` to `c = n - 1` except it hit's the `break` statement. If it does, it will jump out of the loop. If you never break then your `c` will actually be `n` *after* the loop.

And here is why. The loop works like this:

1. initialize the for loop with `c = 2`
2. Check for condition `(c <= n - 1)`
   if true: execute loop body
   if false: jump past loop
3. increment `c` by one
4. goto 2.

Example: Suppose your `n` is 3.

1. we set `c` to 2, now `c == 2` and `n == 3`
2. `2 <= 3 - 1` is true, so the loop body will be executed
3. we increment c by 1, now `c == 3` and `n == 3`
4. we go back to 2. in the description
5. `3 <= 3 - 1` is false, so we don't execute the loop body now and jump out of the loop
6. after we left the loop `c == 3` and `n == 3` so `c == n`

So if we never hit the break statement `c` will be equal to `n` after the loop. We hit the break statement *if* n is not prime. If we break `c` will miss *at least* one increment and thus `c < n` after the loop. Now `c == n` will evaluate to false and the if statements body of `if ( c == n )` will not be executed.

Now to the `if ( n%c == 0 )`. `n%c`means `n` modulo `c`, so the remainder of the division of `n` by `c`. If this remainder is 0 then `c` is an integer divisor of `n`. So in the loop you are testing `n` for any divisor bigger than 1 and smaller than `n`.

If there is a divisor of `n` except 1 and itself, `n` can't be prime. So if you hit any `c` with `1 < c < n` that makes `n%c`equal to 0 `n` can't be prime.

Hint: You don't have to test for divisors bigger than `√n`.

Comment: The question isn't very clear, but to my reading this doesn't answer it.

Comment: You are right, too. ;) I answered the question before it was rephrased and interpreted it wrong. I hope my edit answers the question better.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that `c` ends up being `n - 1` is *incorrect*. If you step through your program with the debugger you should see that for `n == 11`, `c == 11` at the end of the loop.

If we don't break early then the last time the loop body executes is indeed when `c == n - 1` however `c` is then incremented and the loop invariant test fails so after the loop `c == n`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what it means when you say that a number is prime.
A number p is prime when for every `n>1, n<p`,  the remainder `r = 0` for `p/n = r`.

So, this loop runs through each value (c) the range `[2..p-1]`, testing for the remainder.

```
int isprime = 1; //use a flag to indicate prime, assume prime until proven otherwise
for ( c = 2 ; //initialize c=2, the first value in the range [2..p-1]
      c <= n - 1 ; //check whether c is still in the range [2..p-1]
      c++ ) //increment c to the next value in the range [2..p-1]
{
    if ( n % c == 0 ) //modulo '%' is the remainder of the integer division
    {
        isprime = 0;
        break;
    }
}
printf("%d %s prime.\n", n, isprime?"is":"is not");
```

Rather than test that the number is prime by checking a side effect of the loop counter, why not set a flag before the loop, and then test it as the decision for prime at the end?  The result is code that is less fragile, error-prone, and clearer.

Want to save about half the work?  Once you test `n%2`, we know that there is no number k such that `k*2=n`, right?  so check the range `[2..p/2]`, and change your loop to,

```
for( c = 2; c <= n/2; c++ )
```

Can you think of a number smaller than `n/2` that works?

An interesting algorithm for finding multiple primes is the [Sieve of Erastosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: Instead  use for (c= 2; c<=(int)sqrt(n); c++)